# Word documents remain checked out after I upload them in SharePoint Library 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library

I have a SP library with 2 mandatory content type column. When users are uploading(dragging) the documents then some documents remains checked out and some gets automatically checked in. I can not change the properties of those column. Need a out of the box solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2016 and below require Required columns to have properties before it will allow check in. What I would suggest is setting a default value for those columns, if possible, which should allow the document to be uploaded.

Alternatively, you can create a workflow that runs on new/updated item that sets a value if none exist for those specific columns.

And lastly, you can use a [Remote] Event Receiver if those solutions will not work for you, but that will require development knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

This is caused by two things:

1. You have at least one column in the library configured to be a required field.
2. Under the library’s Version Settings, “Require Check Out” is set to “Yes”.

Go to Library Settings->click the Versioning settings->In the Require Check Out section, under the "Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?" question, select No.

Reference:

http://www.crowbarsolutions.com/solution-checked-out-items-or-documents-when-uploading-multiple-documents-in-sharepoint/

https://help.bittitan.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011963128-Why-are-my-SharePoint-documents-showing-as-checked-out-after-migration-